# PHP encryption / decryption adding padded characters

Tags: php, encryption, character-encoding, blowfish, password-encryption

I'm trying to create a simple Encryption class but the resulting string is being padded with non-ascii characters. I've tried rtrim(), converting to utf8, etc. as mentioned in some other answers. What exactly am I missing? Here is what the characters show up when pasting the results into Notepad++

[image]

Pastebin containing the characters [here](http://pastebin.com/hXPtuZin). Appears as 't' in html, but copying that into notepad shows the random bits of data after it.

```
class Crypter implements ICrypter {

private $Key;
private $Algo;

public function __construct($Algo = MCRYPT_BLOWFISH) {

    $this->Key = substr('key', 0, mcrypt_get_key_size($Algo, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    $this->Algo = $Algo;

}

public function Encrypt($data) {

    //$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->Algo, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    //$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

    $blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size('blowfish', 'ecb'); // get block size
    $pkcs = $blocksize - (strlen($data) % $blocksize); // get pkcs5 pad length
    $data.= str_repeat(chr($pkcs), $pkcs); // append pkcs5 padding to the data


    $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt($this->Algo, $this->Key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    return rtrim(base64_encode($crypt));

}

public function Decrypt($data) {

    $crypt = base64_decode($data);
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->Algo, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypt = mcrypt_decrypt($this->Algo, $this->Key, $crypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    return rtrim($decrypt);
}
 }
```

Comment: I think you should put the `incorrect` results that you got. But if you know what area the `bad` chars you could need try to pass it as a secondary arg for the rtrim. If no argument was passed rtrim will try just remote the whitespaces, not other 'strange' characters.

Comment: Appears to be a character of binary '110' according to Notepad++ converter. Appears as a long hyphen in ASCII using the converter.

Comment: Try `rtrim(base64_encode($crypt), "\x110")` and return what happens. Please post a pastebin with your 'bad' output too.

Comment: Ended up completely changing the rest of the output. Pastebin of the pasted result ('t' with some sort of data afterwards) added to the question. Copying from pastebin to notepad does show something afterwards.

Comment: Appears to be my padding during encryption. Removed it and appears to be working.

Comment: The encrypted result is not text and should not be modified. Every byte and their value have a purpose as is and if you call trim() or some other bs, you cannot decrypt it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to handle the padding in the decryption same as the encryption. Here is a working example of your code:

```
<?php
class Crypter{

    private $Key;
    private $Algo;

    public function __construct($Algo = MCRYPT_BLOWFISH) {

        $this->Key = substr('key', 0, mcrypt_get_key_size($Algo, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
        $this->Algo = $Algo;

    }

    public function Encrypt($data) {

        //$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->Algo, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        //$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

        $blocksize = mcrypt_get_block_size('blowfish', 'ecb'); // get block size
        $pkcs = $blocksize - (strlen($data) % $blocksize); // get pkcs5 pad length
        $data.= str_repeat(chr($pkcs), $pkcs); // append pkcs5 padding to the data


        $crypt = mcrypt_encrypt($this->Algo, $this->Key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);

        return rtrim(base64_encode($crypt));

    }

    public function Decrypt($data) {

        $crypt = base64_decode($data);
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->Algo, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypt = mcrypt_decrypt($this->Algo, $this->Key, $crypt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);

        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('blowfish', 'ecb');
        $pad = ord($decrypt[($len = strlen($decrypt)) - 1]);
        return substr($decrypt, 0, strlen($decrypt) - $pad);
    }
}

$crypter = new Crypter();
$data = "Some data to encrypt";
$encryptedData = $crypter->Encrypt($data);
$decryptedData = $crypter->Decrypt($encryptedData);
echo "Decrypted Data = [$decryptedData]\n";
```

Notice the three lines I replaced your original `Decrypt()` return line with.

Comment: Pretty much identical to what I did, completely forgot the unpadding. Thanks!